# Add dependency to .net core csproj file

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, csproj

I am using prerelase version of .net core (build 1.0.0-preview3-004031). There is no project.json files and they replaced with csproj.

I can't find any sample describing how to add dependency to csproj for .net core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a few information about the .net core `csproj` in the [.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/).

There you'll find a `csproj` sample and also how to migrate from `project.json` to `csproj`. <s>There's also a link to [project.json to csproj mapping by scenario](https://gist.github.com/srivatsn/31a2d9cd3607c24a0108c813d4cbc51e).</s>

Comment: Thanks for links, they helped me a lot.