# Adding framework imports to .csproj

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

How do I add framework imports to the `.csproj` file?
In **project.json** it looked like:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": [
            "dotnet5.6",
            "portable-net45+win8"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now in the `.csproj` file all I see is:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

How do I add in the "imports"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to create a project in 'old' format and make a reference to a .net core app?

Comment: I installed VS2017, and I am updating a Core 1.0 app to Core 1.1.  The new layout of the project in VS2017 removes project.json and now uses a .csproj file.  A few packages will not work with netcoreapp1.1 so I need to add framework imports (portable-net45+win8)

Comment: Now I understand you. =) Take a look in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460296/add-dependency-to-net-core-csproj-file)

Comment: Ok, I got it working.  I missed one line updating to 1.1... <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>

Comment: Nice! Make sure to upvote the answer there to help others. Or make a comment telling us if you had to make some extra work to get it working.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I got it working. I missed one line updating to 1.1...

```
<PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
```